# arraycopy in Binary Search

Tags: java

I need help with my code here please. I wanted it display the arrays every time it is splitted while containing the key value until it arrives with the simplest array with key value in it then it display "Found!". My problem is, it worked for key = 2 only and not others keys. Please help me for that.

```
   package Search;
    import java.util.*;
    public class BinarySearch{
/**Example is below of what I expected which is a result I obtained from key = 2

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2]

Found!
**/
        public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key){
            int low = 0;
            int high = list.length;

            while(high >= low){    
                int mid = (low+high)/2;

                int[] temp = new int[high];
                System.arraycopy(list, low, temp, 0, high);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
                int count = 0;
                if(key < list[mid]){
                    high = mid - 1;
                    if(count<temp.length){

                    }
                }
                else if(key == list[mid]){
                    return mid;
                }
                else{
                    low = mid + 1;
                }   
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public static int User(){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter key: ");
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            int user = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return user;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

            System.out.println("The array: "+Arrays.toString(list));
            System.out.println("The key is found at "+BinarySearch.binarySearch(list, BinarySearch.User()));
        }

}
```

Comment: please describe it more

Comment: That's approximately [what I get](http://ideone.com/5LBqsE), what's the problem? E: for higher keys there is some trouble but you did not ask about that

Comment: The program should output the list it will search for every time the list is reduced by half until the

number is found or not found.

Comment: Yes I need help with that for higher keys

Comment: Look at your start positions. The array you need does not go from 0 to high, it goes from low to high.

Comment: It almost work when I replaced "low" with 0, but didn't further reduce the array

Comment: Try it the other way around - you're *already* using 0 as the starting position (implicitly), now stop doing that. The array you're extracting is meant to go from low to high, not from 0 to high. The temp array is too big now.